# Jquery detect when div has scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Searching for this on Google yields numerous results which I could not get to work. What is an absolute method of detecting when a user has reached the bottom of a div? That is when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the div which has scrollbars of its own.

Comment: What do you mean by, "reached"?  Does the `<div>` have scrollbars?

Comment: Yes, when the user has scrolled to the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be something like if the scrollHeight = scrollTop + offsetHeight of the element then you reached the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, using these in Jquery didn't seem to work (as properties or functions) but when I skipped the Jquery and did it in plain javascript it worked great.